# Hiding elements in table causes columns to shift

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In this example http://jsfiddle.net/bYAK4/ why does hiding a cell cause the whole column to shift over and what can I do to avoid this?

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td><div class="hide">World</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width:400px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hide').slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hide').hide();
});
```

`slideUp` may causes the meshup and also give width to `td` like

```
table tr td{
    width:200px;
}
```

See this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bYAK4/1/)

See this using `slideUp` [**DEMO2**](http://jsfiddle.net/bYAK4/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I see now why the problem is happening.  Is there a workaround if I still want to hide it with slideUp?

Comment: Ahh gotcha, so you have to rigidly enforce the td width. Thanks a lot! Learned something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're essentially removing it from the dom, but not destroying it.

If you only want to hide it use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hide').css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like jQuery is animating the width of the td, in either .slideUp() or even if you use .hide(1000).

Try adding width to the td instead of the table:

```
td { width: 200px; }
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frankfajardo/jUb5j/). I added a border around the td so you can see what happens.